# Maximizing the funciton $f(x,y,z) = x^2 + 2y - z^2$

Tags: calculus

Solve this for $x$ and $z$. Any help? Been trying for like thirty minutes, no success. Maybe just tired, or it's impossible to solve.

$$\begin{cases}2x = 8 \lambda\\
2 = \mu - \lambda\\
-2z = \mu\\
\end{cases}$$

**Edit**

> Maximize the function $f(x,y,z) = x^2 + 2y - z^2$ subject to the constraints $8x - y = 0$ and $y + z = 0$.

We have that $\nabla f = 2x \hat{i} + 2 \hat{j} -2z \hat{k}$. Let $g_1 = 8x - y$ and $g_2 = y + z$. Then $\nabla g_1 = 8 \hat{i} - \hat{j}$ and $\nabla g_2 = \hat{j} + {k}$.

Now using Lagrange's method: $\nabla f = \lambda \nabla g_1 + \mu \nabla g_2$.

This gives $2x \hat{i} + 2 \hat{j} - 2z \hat{k} = 8 \lambda \hat{i} + (\mu - \lambda)\hat{j} + \mu \hat{k}$, or the next system of equations:
$$\begin{cases}2x = 8 \lambda\\
2 = \mu - \lambda\\
-2z = \mu\\
\end{cases}$$

Comment: When you say that these equations have to be solved for $x$ and $z$, then I assume that $\mu$ and $\lambda$ are some given constants. Then the second equation doesn't contain any information on $x$ and $z$ at all and can be ignored.

From the first equation you get $x = 4\lambda$ and from the third one $z = -0.5\mu$. Or did I miss anything?

Comment: Solve with respect to what? Because if you take the first and third equations, the system is already solved for $x$ and $z$. Which variable do you want to remove?

Comment: For the ones interested, I edited my post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

maximize $f = x^2 + 2y-z^2 $ subject to the constraints $y =8x$ and $y=-z.$

won't this work.

$$f = x^2 + 2y-z^2 = x^2+16x - 64x^2 = -63x^2 +16x \le -63 \times \left(\frac8{63}\right)^2 + 16 \times \frac{8}{63} = \frac{64}{63} $$  this is achieved at $x = \frac{8}{63}, y =\frac{64}{63}, z = -\frac{64}{63}.$

Comment: Is $64/63$ the answer according to you? I need to find an $x, y, z$ such that the function achieves maximum value.

Comment: Thanks, I inserted that answer and it was correct! Although the method you've used to find it is not so clear to me O.O

Comment: @Kamil, what do you mean? a quadratic expression $ax^2 + bx + c$ has a local maximum at $x = -b/(2a)$ is $a < 0.$ that is what i used ti find the maximum value.

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple ways of solving that system for $x$ and $z$. Since $\mu$ and $\lambda$ are constant, the system is already in a *solved* state: just take the first and third equations, and you get:
$$\begin{cases}x = 4\lambda\\
z = -\frac12\mu
\end{cases}$$

If, however, you want to remove the dependence on one of these constants, you can make use of the second equation to get either
$$\begin{cases}x = 4\lambda\\
z = -1-\frac12\lambda
\end{cases}$$
or
$$\begin{cases}x = 4\mu-8\\
z = -\frac12\mu
\end{cases}$$

Comment: I edited my post, to make my intentions clear.

Comment: @Kamil: Ah I see. This is an entirely different question altogether. Unfortunately I don't know how to help you, I don't know about the Lagrange method!